# Importing open tickets from trac to jira

Tags: jira, trac, jira-plugin

We are using trac for bug tracking as of now and migrating to jira soon. I am able to migrate an entire trac repository to jira using [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACLOUD/Importing+Data+from+Trac#ImportingDatafromTrac-RunningtheTracImportWizard) and it is working fine. How can I import only the open tickets from trac to jira? Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using csv import/export. I don't know if trac can export to csv, but jira can import csv files.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to write a short script that uses XML-RPC to read from Trac and write to JIRA.  That way, you can have full control over which things are imported and how.  For Trac, you will need the [XmlRpcPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin).  Information about JIRA's XML-RPC interface can be found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/jira-xml-rpc-overview) (with sample code [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/jira-xml-rpc-overview/creating-an-xml-rpc-client)).  The Trac plugin's page includes sample code in several languages.  You should be able to re-purpose some of that code to get you started.